How to build an nginx conf to accommodate wildcards in location?
I have a server and 2 locations. The proxy_pass is the same for both but I need to pass a different header
server {

   location ~ /deployments/*xx*/ {
      proxy_pass $uri;
      proxy_set_header custom-header val1
   }

   location ~ /deployments/*yy*/ {
      proxy_pass $uri;
      proxy_set_header custom-header val2
   }

}

Is this the right way to use regex to accommodate the wildcard uri? What would be the best way to implement this?
The reason I can't use different request paths is because I am not sure how many paths there might be. But all the paths containing 'xx' need header to val1 and paths containing 'yy' need header to val2.
I have tried location ~ /deployments/*xx*/ { ... } and location ~ /deployments/.*xx.*/ { ... }. Neither seem to hit the right endpoint
